# SQL script works in MySQL, but fails with mysqli->query(); why?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My SQL script works successfully in MySQL Workbench.

The following gives an error:

```php
$link = mysqli_connect(***********);
$result = $link->query($sql);
```

The SQL script performs some actions including:

- create temporary table
- truncate table
- drop table
- insert
- select

I am getting an error when executing this:

```sql
-- 1.1 Creating temporary table for categories

    drop table if exists exp_categories; -- just in case
    create temporary table exp_categories
    (
        ID bigint not null,
        Categories text not null,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- 1.2 Inserting data...
-- few other statements here
-- last statement is SELECT
```

Does mysqli have limitations that I am encountering?

Comment: Your message is a bit unclear.  What is the error and where does it occur?

Comment: Does the user you connect with has necessary privileges in the db to drop and create tables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use `multi_query()`

> Multiple statements or multi queries must be executed with
>   [mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php). The individual statements of the statement
>   string are separated by semicolon.

```php
$link->multi_query($sql)
```

And the user you connect with have to have necessary privileges in your db or global privileges.

Comment: Thanks. But finally i had to explode my sql file to separate queries to avoid additional procedure for multiple queries.